# Next.js: How Can I Make Dynamic Routes With Spaces Work?

Tags: routes, next.js

I have a `getStaticPaths` function that generates two nearly identical paths: `foo%20bar` and `foo_bar`.  My `foo_bar` path works great, but for some reason the `foo%20bar` path doesn't work: it routes to my 404 page (whether I literally browse to `foo%20bar` or just `foo bar`).

Is there some trick to make URIEncoded spaces (ie. `%20`) work in dynamic Next.js routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, that isn't possible yet as reported [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11016).

You can use `encodeURIComponent` on the `foo%20bar` path in your `getStaticPaths`, but it'll only be accessible as `foo%2520bar` in the browser, and not `foo%20bar` as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem but the reason was using **--turbo** flag in **dev scripts** in *package.json*. After researching for a bit I found out that the rust based turbopack bundler causes this problem, So I removed the **--turbo** flag and by compiling with native next.js webpack compiler the problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

When returning parms in `getStaticPaths` you can use `decodeURIComponent` to map the `path` with spaces, the `space` maps to `%20` in browser and renders the route

```
const dummyPaths = dummyAPIResponse.map((id: string) => {
    return {
        params: {
            id: decodeURIComponent(id.toLowerCase()),
        },
    };
});
```

Discussion from github: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54096