# Next.js – encodeURIComponent doesn't work with `/` in `getStaticPaths`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

- Minimal repro site: https://nextjs-paths-issue.vercel.app/
- Minimal repro code: https://github.com/saadq/nextjs-encoding-issue

  - [Home page](https://github.com/saadq/nextjs-encoding-issue/blob/main/src/pages/index.tsx)
  - [Food page](https://github.com/saadq/nextjs-encoding-issue/blob/main/src/pages/food/%5BfoodTitle%5D.tsx)

I am trying to iterate through an array of food objects and create static pages for each one based on its title. This works for most of the foods, but if the food title contains a `/`, then navigating to the page (such as [the **"Nice strawberry/kiwis dessert"** page](https://nextjs-paths-issue.vercel.app/food/Nice%20strawberry%2Fkiwis%20dessert)) will throw a 404.

In the home page, I encode the URL when I [create the `Link`](https://github.com/saadq/nextjs-encoding-issue/blob/main/src/pages/index.tsx#L11) and then in the [`getStaticPaths` function](https://github.com/saadq/nextjs-encoding-issue/blob/main/src/pages/food/%5BfoodTitle%5D.tsx#L26), I create the `paths` using the same encoded link. However, it doesn't seem to work when deployed.

The page does work locally when running `npm run dev`, but it seems that in the actual output build there are issues. Is there something I can do to allow paths with encoded slashes to work?

---

**Home page**

```
const HomePage: NextPage = () => (
  <>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <ul>
      {foods.map((food) => (
        <li key={food.title}>
          <Link href={`/food/${encodeURIComponent(food.title)}`}>
            {food.title}
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </>
)
```

**Food page**

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<Props, Params> = (ctx) => {
  const title = ctx.params?.foodTitle as string
  const food = foods.find((food) => food.title === title) as Food

  return {
    props: {
      food
    }
  }
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = () => {
  const paths = foods.map((food) => `/food/${encodeURIComponent(food.title)}`)

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}

const FoodPage: NextPage<Props> = ({ food }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Link href='/'>Go Back</Link>
      <h1>{food.title}</h1>
      <h2>Amount: {food.amount}</h2>
    </>
  )
}

export default FoodPage
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js: How Can I Make Dynamic Routes With Spaces Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66270207/next-js-how-can-i-make-dynamic-routes-with-spaces-work)

Comment: @juliomalves That seems to be about spaces though right? Links with `%20` don't seem to be causing an issue themselves, it just seems to be when the `/` is involved. For example, this link is working: https://nextjs-paths-issue.vercel.app/food/Pears%20%26%20Bananas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example I posted here is a bit contrived, for my actual app I was able to get it to work by using `fallback: 'blocking'`. It's not a totally exportable static website anymore unfortunately, but I only have a few pages that will run into this issue so it's fine that a few of them will have a slight loading time from the server.

---

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

> // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
> // { fallback: blocking } will server-render pages
> // on-demand if the path doesn't exist.
> return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' }

Answer (score 1):

An old thread, but I've spent many hours looking for a solution so I'd like to share.

In order to get links in the format /categories/page in getStaticPath, and at the same time to use the same component in the /category/ and in the /category/page/, but with different parameters, you should use the page format [...category].js. This allows you to pass parameters in getStaticPaths as an array:

```
params: {
    category: [category, page],
}
```

In result it will generate page category/page and still have fallback: false.
Trying to add '/' directly to the path (as you did) creates html pages category%2fpage.html.

[More details about static paths](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths)
[And about catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Ofc, because you have `/` in the path. `%2F` symbol representing `/`

Just make custom function for `path` encoding and use it

```
static stringToParamUrl(input: string) {      
    let url = input.normalize("NFD").toLowerCase().replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/g, "-")
    return url
  }
```

**Modifications:**
"*I create the paths using the same encoded link. However, it doesn't seem to work when deployed.*" if it's worked it is not correct. Your other links are working exept those containing "/". "/" is a reserved character for the URL. In next js it's working as "separator".

Also (about **Link**):
You [need to have](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag) `<a>` tag in `Link`

```
<Link><a>something</a></Link>
```

Also (about **fallback**):

Fallback [is not changing the](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag) logic of URLs. Using fallback will generate static page on the "first demand" - nothing about URL not working.
You had no errors during deployment time because you didn't create static page (fallback false)

What you need:
*"I am trying to iterate through an array of food objects and create static pages for each one based on its title."* = you need to add to your database a field called "URL" or something like this, and iterate elements based on URL *you previously generated while creating your array) and not name, because:

1. You need to have "unique" URL (to get data from your api via [pid] parameters or something)
2. You need to [avoid reserved and forbidden](https://developers.google.com/maps/url-encoding) symbols in URL
3. It's better to prettify url. ( I shared a function with you)

Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly

Comment: *Ofc, because you have / in the path. %2F symbol representing /*

I'm a bit confused on what you mean by this. Isn't the point of encoding so that things like `/` get converted into things like `%2F` and then it isn't an issue if those symbols are a part of the URL?

Comment: Please chack modifications of my post